# Different ways to interpret compound-complex sentences

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, compound-complex

Compound-Complex Sentences:

Do adverb dependent clause in a compound-complex sentence modify multiple independent clauses?

It seems like if the adverb dependent clause is at the beginning position, it is more likely to modify both independent clauses, while at the end position, it seems to merely modify the independent clause followed by it.

Let's take the compound-complex sentence below as an example; the dependent clause is at the end position.

> The man believed in the system, and he knew that justice would prevail after the murderer was sent to jail. (Source: https://reurl.cc/RdW3Me)

In my opinion, the order of the events might differ according to different ways to interpret to the sentence.

First way

> (The event of the first independent main clause happened first. Then after the "after" clause, the event of the second independent clause happened.)
>
> The order:
>
> The man believed in the system > The murder was sent to jail > The man knew the justice would prevail

Second way

> (Events in both independent clauses happened after the "after" clause.)
>
> The order:
>
> The murder was sent to jail > The man believed in the system > The man knew the justice would prevail

Finally, if we rephrase the example sentence to:

> After the murderer was sent to jail, the man believed in the system, and he knew that justice would prevail.

or a sentence like this:

> After the two soccer players lost their game, they joined their other teammates for lunch, and they went to the movies. (Source: https://reurl.cc/RdW3Me)

It is clear, from my point of view, that both events of the independent clauses happened after the dependent clause's event.

Of course, I might be wrong. If there is anything wrong, please correct me and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: There's no reason why a fronted adjunct can't have scope over the coordination.

Comment: How about the dependent clause at the end position like my example: The man believed in the system, and he knew that justice would prevail after the murderer was sent to jail.

Comment: The original phrasing doesn't quite make sense. If the man didn't know that justice would prevail until *after* the murderer was sent to jail, then I would question his belief in the system. This is a bad example to make a complex analysis of because it is - at least - ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually, my post here is trying to ask whether the dependent clause (at the beginning position or at end position) can have scope over the multiple independent clauses. My guess is that at the beginning can have scope over, but at the end can't or is more unlikely. Please help me with this. Thank you.